# Typescript custom tool, transpiler, extension

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, compilation, visual-studio-code

I would like to alter/check `.ts` files before `tsc` will start its transpilation process, similar to what *Roslyn* provides for C#.

This is useful for static type checking. For example, proper and short `Immutable Record` implementation requires code altering/static check at compile time, as it can be done with [Flow](https://blog.stephanbehnke.com/hunt-for-immutable-type-safe-record-in-javascript/):

```
@Record(Person)
interface IPerson {  
  givenName: string;
  familyName: string;
}
```

and then custom tsc transpiler could modify code to:

```
interface IPersonParams {  
  givenName?: string;
  familyName?: string;
}
@Record()
class Person {  
  private readonly __givenName;
  private readonly __familyName;
  constructor(init) {
    this.__givenName = init.givenName;
    this.__familyName = init.familyName;
  }
  get givenName() {
    return this.__givenName;
  }
  get familyName() {
    return this.__familyName;
  }
  update(update: IPersonParams) {
    // ignore the bug when undefined param is passed
    return new Person({
      givenName: update.givenName || this.__givenName,
      familyName: update.familyName || this.__familyName
    });
  }
}
```

It would be nice to see custom compilation errors immediately as it is done now with Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code, which run special `tsc watch`, not as part of webpack bundling or custom gulp task. There is an API for [Typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API), but how to make it work seamless with `tsc` in `VS/VS Code/Atom`?

---

**Update with examples**

The goal is just to write

```
@Record(Person)
interface IPerson {  
  givenName: string;
  familyName: string;
}
```

1. The class `Person` will be auto generated based on the interface `IPerson` as shown earlier.
2. It will be possible to instantiate the object:

   `let instance = new Person({givenName: "Emma", familyName: "Watson"});`

   Any incorrect property will raise a compilation error:

   `let instance = new Person({nonExistedProperty: "Emma"}); //error`

   Error: Property 'nonExistedProperty' does not exist in class Person constructor;
   Error: Property 'givenName' is required in class Person constructor;
   Error: Property 'familyName' is required in class Person constructor;
3. Existing object should be able to be partially updated

   `let instance = new Person({givenName: "Emma", familyName: "Watson"});`
   `instance.Update({givenName: "Luise"});`

   `instance.givenName === "Luise"; //TRUE;`
   `instance.familyName === "Watson"; //TRUE;`
4. All properties are readonly

   `let instance = new Person({givenName: "Emma", familyName: "Watson"});`
   `instance.givenName = "John"; //error`

   Error: Property 'givenName' is readonly;
5. `Equals` method is autogenerated. It can be based on hash or anything else, but should work fast and provide a deep check.

   `let instance1 = new Person({givenName: "Emma", familyName: "Watson"});`
   `let instance2 = new Person({givenName: "Emma", familyName: "Watson"});`

   `instance1.Equals(instance2); //TRUE`

   It might also have a place for controlling created instances and if a record   with the same parameters exists in internal dictionary then it just returns the reference to this object:

   `let instance1 = new Person({givenName: "Emma", familyName: "Watson"});`
   `let instance2 = new Person({givenName: "Emma", familyName: "Watson"});`

   `instance1 == instance2; //TRUE`
   `instance1 === instance2; //TRUE`

Comment: Could you please give one or more usage examples?
How would the user code look like when your decorator is interpreted the way you imagine? What would be possible, what would be restricted?

Comment: Just remembered the fact that you cannot annotate interfaces in TypeScript. The workaround here is to use classes instead of interfaces: `interface A {} ... class B implements A {}`

Comment: @Benjamin the problem is deeper than interface annotations. Compiler cannot fully check dynamically created objects. Typescript annotations allow only dynamically created objects, but not static. That's why there is a need of a custom intermediate compilation tool, which can create classes (static) that will be further fully checked by a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of writing your own typescript (pre) processor, you could achieve your goals by using TypeScript decorators.

This example is from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html:

```
@sealed
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

function sealed(constructor: Function) {
    Object.seal(constructor);
    Object.seal(constructor.prototype);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It was my first attempt to check it, but there is a problem: to correctly understand the structure of an object the code should be ready for a static analysis.

 It means that by creating dynamic objects like `obj[someVarProp] = propValue` a compiler cannot understand and check the correctness of code. Thus this procedure should be made closely with a compiler, like it is possible to do  in Roslyn project.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've found so far. There is no simple way to do it at this moment (2017).

One solution is to create a custom plugin that will use Typescript API. It will also run the services second time in its own sandbox alongside with TS services in `VS Code`, `Atom` or `VS`. In addition to this each IDE will require its own plugin to be created as a wrapper on top of your core plugin/service.

In this way some people already made linters, for example, [vscode-ng-language-service](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service) and [ng2linter](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/02/29/static-code-analysis-angular-typescript/).

Microsoft has [#6508](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6508) ticket for TypeScript extensibility, which will make the requested features possible and simple to implement.

---

For those who program in `C#` and `F#` it might be better to use the possibilities of `Roslyn` instead of waiting TypeScript extensions. A code written in C# can be transpiled to TypeScript or JavaScript. It also opens the wide possibilities for all kind of checking and custom modifications. And of course it is more close to [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) if there is the same logic in `.NET` and `TypeScript/Javascript`. [Bridge.NET](http://bridge.net/) does not use Roslyn, but has a good implementation. [Rosetta](https://github.com/andry-tino/Rosetta) project for .NET 4 and Roslyn seems to be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

This is all possible without any compiler magic.

external libs

```
declare function someGenericEqualsFn(a, b): boolean;
declare function makeCached<TResult, TFunc extends (...args) => TResult>(funcToCache: TFunc): TFunc;
declare function merge<T>(objectToUpdate: T, objectToMerge: Partial<T>);
```

our lib:

```
interface DataRecord<TRecord> {
    equals<TRecord>(other: TRecord): boolean;
    update(update: Partial<TRecord>);
}

function createDataRecord<TRecord>(data: TRecord): Readonly<TRecord> & DataRecord<TRecord> {
    const result: TRecord & DataRecord<TRecord> = <any>{};
    Object.keys(data).forEach(() => {

    });

    result.equals = function (other: TRecord) {
        return someGenericEqualsFn(result, other);
    };

    result.update = function (partial: Partial<TRecord>) {
        merge(result, partial);
    };

    return result;
}
```

our test:

```
interface IPerson {
    givenName: string;
    familyName: string;
}

let instance = createDataRecord<IPerson>({givenName: "Emma", familyName: "Watson"});
instance = createDataRecord<IPerson>({nonExistedProperty: "Emma"}); // compiler error
instance.givenName = "John";             // compiler error
instance.update({givenName: "Emma"});     //   works!
instance.update({nonExistedProperty: "x"});      // compiler error

const createDataRecordOrGetCached = makeCached(createDataRecord);
let instance1 = createDataRecordOrGetCached({givenName: "Emma", familyName: "Watson"});
let instance2 = createDataRecordOrGetCached({givenName: "Emma", familyName: "Watson"});

instance1 == instance2; //TRUE
instance1 === instance2; //TRUE
```

Comment: This does not answer the general question, but resolves one of my big project problems. Thank you very much @Benjamin for you help! Very, very handy! Mapped types indeed resolve the problem with partial update and readonly fields.